# Are there any other devas than the 33 named in Scripture?

Tags: scripture, vedas, gods

33 devas are named in the Vedas. But are there any indications, in the Vedas or in any other writings, that there exist other devas, that are not named in the Vedas, and are not manifestations of the 33 named ones?

Comment: Downvote trolls go away

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are many more Devas besides the 33 main gods and the ones that are easy to name are:

1. The Avatars of Lord Vishnu like **Krishna, Rama, Matsya, Kurma etc**,
2. The sons of Lord Shiva - **Kartikey and Ganesha**,
3. **Yamaraj** - the overlord of the underworld,
4. **Kuber** - the treasurer of the gods,
5. **Durga** and the various forms of Aadi Shakti would all feature in the list as well.

Some of these Devas are derived from the 33 like the below example from the chapter on the description of the [Manidvipa from the Devi Bhagwat Puran](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57413.html):

> O King! **Īsāna, the Regent of the north eastern quarter lives here with Bhadrakālī and other Mātrigaṇas, with Koṭis and Koṭis of Rudrāṇīs and with Ḍāmarīs and Vīra Bhadras and various other Śaktis**. On his neck there is a garland of skulls, on his hand there is a ring of snakes; he wears a tiger skin; his upper clothing is a tiger skin and his body is smeared with the ashes of the dead. He sounds frequently his Ḍamaru; this sound reverberates on all sides, he makes big laughs called Attahāsya, reverberating through the heavens. He remains always surrounded with Pramathas and Bhūtas; they live here.

However, there are many more divine beings mentioned in the [next chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57414.html) such as the Shaktis of 64 kalas who are relatively lesser known:

> Piṅgalākṣī, Viśālākṣī, Samriddhi, Vriddhi, Śraddhā, Svāhā, Svadhā, Māyā, Sañgñā, Vasundharā, Trīlokadhātrī, Sāvitrī, Gāyatrī, Tridaśeśvsrī, Surūpā, Bahurūpā, Skandamātā, Acyutapriyā, Vimalā, Amalā, Aruṇī, Ārunī, Prakriti, Vikriti, Śrīṣṭi, Sthiti, Saṃrhiti, Sandhyā, Mātā, Satī, Hamsī, Mardikā, Vajrikā, Parā, Devamātā, Bhagavatī, Devakī, Kamalāsanā, Trimukhī, Saptamukhī, Surāsura vimardinī, Lamboṣṭhī, Ūrdhakeśī, Bahusīrṣā, Vrikodarī Ratharekhāhvayā, Śaśirekā, Gaganavegā, Pavanavegā, Bhuvanapālā, Madanāturā, Anaṅgā, Anangamathanā, Anangamekhalā, Anangakusumā, Visvarūpā, Surādikā, Kṣayaṃkarī, Akṣyobhyā, Satyavādinī, Bahurūpā, Śucivratā, Udārā and Vāgiṣ’ī. These are the sixty four Kalās. All of them have got luminous faces and long lolling tongues. Fire is always coming out from the faces of all of them. The eyes of all of them are red with anger.

Another good example is the Kamdeva, god of Love and Desire:

> On the western corner exists always **Madana with Rati**, holding noose, goad, bow and arrow. All his amorous attendants reside here, incarnate in their forms.

There are many more that can be added to the list but I shall restrict myself to these to give you an idea about how many divinities exist beyond the main 33 gods.

Comment: Yeah, but those Gods are manifestations of the main 33 Gods, are they not?

Comment: Not at all.. manifestations are only direct expansions such as Rudras from Shiva you can't consider Ganesh and Kartikeya as his manifestations they are different beings even if they're born from him. Same goes for Yama or Kama etc.. The 33 only include Vishnu as an Aditya who is actually Vaman but not the other incarnations. Also the list doesn't contain Devi and her various manifestations which are too numerous to count.

Comment: So do you know why the 33 devas are called the "main" devas? Why are they included in the main list?

Comment: Its simple really.. these were primarily nature gods like Indra, Surya, Vayu, Agni etc. who were in direct control of the environment around the ancient Hindus hence were revered more.

Comment: How would you respond to some of the answers to this question which seem to say there are only 33? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52960/how-many-devas-are-there-in-total

Comment: That's an incorrect statement regarding Purans the person has given references only from Vedas. You can yourself pick up the Puranas about the other deities.. also if there is already a question of a similar nature that you have come across why have u asked it again?

Comment: Also, how many devas, known and unknown to man, can we expect to exist? Is it possible that there are an infinite number of them?